# Как выполнить действие после добавления класса в jq?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, не могу понять, как выполнить действие, после добавления нового класса к блоку?
Я хочу добавить вызов алерта после добавления класса к диву.

PS: у меня класс заливает строку цветом, а алерт вызывается асинхронно и выделение происходит после закрытия алерта, я хочу, чтобы сначала стиль применился, а после вызвался алерт, другими словами наверное сделать синхронное выполнение…

```
… функция клик по кнопке
$(‘.box’).addClass(‘newClass’)
alert(“ok!”)
```

То что выше делает сначала алерт, потом заливку..

```
… пробовал еще так
$(‘.box’).addClass(‘newClass’).done(function(){
alert(“ok!”)})
```

По аналогии с $(post)… не сработало, начал читать, наткнулся на промисы, объекты ожидания и т.п. не смог разобраться, сделал пару примеров, не получилось…

В общем я почитал про promise, done… но так и не разобрался, ничего не получилось, подскажите как сделать?

Comment: Оберните добавление класса в функцию и там пусть будет алерт... покажите больше кода, где и когда вы добавляете класс. Промисы тут совсем не виноваты

Comment: Так это практически весь код и есть. Там код примитивный:$(‘#elem’).on(‘click’, function(){ $(‘.box’).addClass(‘myClass’); alert(“ok”);}. У меня класс просто делает заливку строки, и вылезает алерт, когда алерт вылезает, экран затемняется, и он отключает остальные события jq, я хотел сделать, чтобы строка выделилась до алерта, и на затемненном фоне алерта видно было выделение. А так он выделяет после нажатия ок в алерте…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите `alert` в `setTimeout`

```
$(‘.box’).addClass(‘newClass’)
setTimeout(() => alert(“ok!”), 100)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я об этом думал, но хотелось бы более универсальный вариант, в плане, если дальше раздуется задача, например работы с домом будет больше или будет долгое ожидание чего-либо, тогда таймаут будет сложно по времени подобрать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно показать свой alert с помощью [SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .myClass { color: red; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 class="box">Class Box</h3>
    <input id="elem" type="button" value="Click">
    <script>
      $('#elem').on('click', function(){
          $('.box').addClass('myClass');
          swal('Success', 'OK', 'success');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```